# Power BI Gateway on Remote Desktop Fails Daily

Tags: powerbi, remote-desktop, gateway, vdi, powerbi-gateway

Trying to install a standard gateway on a Remote Desktop.  The gateway works for about 24 hours and then fails.  Once I login to the "On Premise Gateway" app, and restart the gateway it works again for another 24 hours.

The error message the incremental refresh shows is either "DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_SpooledOperationMissing" or "DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_TimeoutError"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thank you!

I have tried restarting the gateway and running the check network check to make sure reaching the ports is successful.

Comment: Aren't DSL connections disconnected by the provider for a few seconds every night?

Answer (score 0):

After a failure log onto the Remote Desktop machine and open Task Manager from the start menu. Go to the Performance tab and then the CPU tab. Note the Uptime metric. If that uptime is just a few minutes then this machine is not “always on”. This is typical for many virtual desktop machines which pause after a period of not being logged into.

[image: Task Manager uptime]

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install#related-considerations):

> Don't install a gateway on a computer, like a laptop, that might be turned off, asleep, or disconnected from the internet. The gateway can't run under any of those circumstances.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thank you for providing a response!  …just had a failure, so checked the CPU uptime and it is still running.  The services tab show the gateway as “running” as well, even though nothing is able to refresh.  Any more suggestions?

Comment: I also verified that sleep mode is turned off completely